# log4net preventing web (.aspx, .ascx, .master) intellisense from working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, log4net, intellisense

When I include log4net in an ASP.NET MVC project, intellisense stops working for master pages, user controls and pages. The first line of the file has a red underline, with the following message:

> ASP.NET runtime error: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

Any idea what the cause of this is? The project builds fine and I can debug and deploy it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Managed to solve it in the end, had the clear the temporary asp.net files folder, `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files`

Comment: Note, I have a similar problem, and this did not specifically fix the problem for me.  Still investigating what the solution is.

Comment: Well, luckly it helped me! +1.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem! I found that you need to delete different locations for win7/x86/x64

Clear out the temporary framework files for your project in:

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\

For **Windows 7**, the path is:

> C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\

For **64 bit** systems with 'Framework' in the path the full path is:

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\

[Found the solution here](http://blkarwasara.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/hresult-0x80070057-einvalidarg-on-debug.html)